# Get values from select options - use values to toggleClass()

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

I have a select box with a number of options. Each option represents a class name that can be selected and added to a div. The div may already have other classes which are not to be touched.

My issue is that I would like to toggle between these classes only - not just keep adding new ones. How can I create a script that loops through all the class names of the select box and toggles between them?

Here's what I have - i just adds classes - it doesn't toggle.

html:

```
<form id="form">
  <div>
    <label for="height">Height:</label>
    <select id="height">
      <option>- Select class -</option>
      <option value="height133">133</option>
      <option value="height55">55</option>
      <option value="otherclass">127</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="go">Submit</button>
</form>
<div class="gridbox otherclass1 otherclass2">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#go").click(function() {
   var height = $("#height").find(":selected").val();
   $(".gridbox").toggleClass(height);
});
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ds3nn5tn/3/).

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Your code does toggle the classes, as can be seen in the DOM inspector. Why do you believe it doesn't? You may be encountering issues with specificity of style rules, but to fix that we would need to know what class should have the highest precedence. Also note you can use just `$("#height").val();`

Comment: Yes, it toggles, but ti doesn't replace the classes from the select box. If you select different options it just keeps adding your choices, like class="height133 height55, etc..." It should only be possible to add ONE of the classes from the select box at the time. Hope this makes sense. :-)

Comment: @Meek Ya make better sense now but your question was quite unclear

Comment: For this kind of behaviour, you should prefix your specific classes and use removeClass wildcard to remove them specifically   https://jsfiddle.net/cwphr4ud/9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove other classes which were added earlier.

```
$("#go").click(function() {
    var heightElem = $("#height");
    var height = heightElem.find("option[value]:selected").val();
    var allClassess = heightElem.find("option[value]") //traverse to all option elements
        .map(function() {
            return this.value ? this.value : null;
        }).get() // Get an array of all the class
        .join(' ') //Create a string;
    $(".gridbox").removeClass(allClassess).addClass(height);
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/cwphr4ud/4/)

Comment: Ya it looks like what OP is looking for even question is quite unclear imho. One thing, i'd guess OP could wish to [toggle the selected class too](https://jsfiddle.net/cwphr4ud/1/), here you cannot remove it but your answer behaviour seems more logical afterall

Comment: @A.Wolff, I think `addClass` is better suited in answer

Comment: @Satpal, exactly - this is the solution I was looking for... Can I ask you - can this solution be easily extended if - say - I have other select boxes with other class names?

Comment: @Meek, Yes the solution can be extended

Comment: One last thing, your code add the default option text as class, it shouldn't imo

Comment: Sorry but still same issue if submit clicked with default option selected, i guess in fact should be: https://jsfiddle.net/cwphr4ud/4/

Comment: So if I have multiple select boxes - how do they add classes respectively? https://jsfiddle.net/cwphr4ud/7/

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the previously selected class in a variable and remove it before you add another class, toggleClass will just add/remove the class.

```
var height = '';
$("#go").click(function() {
  if(height !== '') {
     $(".gridbox").removeClass(height);
  }
  height = $("#height").find(":selected").val();
  $(".gridbox").addClass(height);
});
```